# how to repeat watermark pic on every page of a pdf which is transformed from a html doc that includes several page-break-before/after?

Tags: html, css, pdf, background, page-break

Recently, I'm generating a big pdf from html/CSS, which includes decades of pages. On every page there needs a wartermark picture as background like follows:
[image: watermark picture]

My codes are as follows:

- html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Paginated HTML</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    body {
      background: #fff repeat url("watermark.png");
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    
    div.page {
      page-break-after: always;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>This is Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>This is Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>This is Page 3</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I use Chrome(66.0.3359.139) to print the html to pdf, I gets a pdf with only the first page including the watermark picture in the background:
[image: pdf printed by Chrome]

When I use FireFox(60) to print the html to pdf, I gets a pdf with no page including the watermark picture:
[image: pdf printed by Firefox]

Does anybody know how to extend the watermark picture as background to every page of pdf that generated from html/css? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use the background image style on `<div class="page">` instead of body

Comment: @MohamedRamrami I have tested your suggest and moved the style of body to div.page, then I got a pdf without watermark background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used a div to wrap the whole content of body, and drew the background watermark picture on this div. It seemed to work with a little defect that watermark picture does not extend to the bottom of the last page(red circled in result pdf picture). Any help to eliminate this defect will be appreciated! Additional codes as follows:

-CSS :

```
.watermark
  {
    background: #fff url("watermark.png");
        background-size: 100%;
  }
```

-HTML:

```
<div class="watermark">
  <div class="page">
    <h1>This is Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>This is Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>This is Page 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the result pdf:
[image]